# Make the results from a mysql database search selectable

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a database containing stock items and a webpage that allows you to search through the database for an item type or a specific item number. The results are returned and displayed in a table under the search form.

Currently I do this by saving the results of a mysql query into an array, and then printing the results of the array into a table.

How can I make a result selectable and then have a button such as 'add' that will allow me to retrieve information from the database based only on the selected item.

Edit -

```
<?php
require("header.php");
if(isset($_REQUEST['searching'])){ //check if form has been submitted
connect('final');//connect to DB
//set the values from search form
$field = $_POST['field'];
$query = $_POST['query']; 

    $query = htmlspecialchars($query); // stop HTML characters
    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query); //stop SQL injection

     $data = mysql_query("SELECT *
     FROM stock 
     WHERE stock.Part_Number IN (SELECT stock.Part_Number
     FROM stock
     WHERE upper(stock.$field) LIKE'%$query%')") ;//query the DB with search field in colleumn selected//

     //$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer INNER JOIN address ON customer.ID = address.Customer_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN sites ON address.ID = sites.address_ID WHERE upper(customer.$field) LIKE'%$query%'") ;

    if($data === FALSE) {
    $error = 'Query error:'.mysql_error();
    echo $error;
    }
    else
    {

    $test = array();
    $colNames = array();
    while($results = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)){// puts data from database into array, loops until no more

    $test[] = $results;

        }
    $colNames = array_keys(reset($test));


        $anymatches=mysql_num_rows($data); //checks if the querys returned any results
            if ($anymatches == 0) 
                    { 
                        echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query<br><br>"; 
                    } 

    }
```

then below in my html form I create a table and have

```
<?php
   //print the header
   foreach($colNames as $colName)
   {
      echo "<th>$colName</th>";
   }
?>
```

and

```
<?php
   //print the rows
   foreach($test as $results)
   {
      echo "<tr>";
      foreach($colNames as $colName)
      {
         echo "<td>".$results[$colName]."</td>";
      }
      echo "</tr>";
   }
?>
```

I wasn't really sure where to start but I will try the checkbox method.

Comment: Could you add your code to the question, please? What have you tried, and why didn't it work?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are many ways to adjust the search to the user's liking.

The most basic solution that only requires php and html would be to have checkboxes at the cells you want to use as a filter.

Then you can add the new parts to the old mysql-command with an and-connection.
 e.g. a checkbox for the "name"-column where the next search will only show entries with the checked names.

`<input type="checkbox" name="names[]" id="chWalter" value="Walter" /> <label for="chWalter">chWalter</label>`

When posted you could run through the checkbox-array with a loop and add something like

`" and name like '".$_GET['names'][$i]."'"`.

Note that using groups with checkboxes will give you an Array of all activated element's values.

Of course you could modify how a checked checkbox alters the previously request... for removing Filters, you could use regular expressions on the request-string.

A nicer solution would be using javascript. e.g. you could use hidden checkboxes that are checked by click on the table-cells.

Or you could just use javascript to filter the Elements! Using classes and

`document.getElementsByClassName['class']`

will lighten your server-traffic and speed up the request. for that, I recommend to use a class for each row (row1, row2, etc.) and one for each column (name, id, etc. ). Then when click on a field, get all elements of the same column class and loop through them.

If their content mismatches, go through their row-class and set a css-attribtue like "display:none"... if you use a table-layout you can replace the use of the row-classes with something like

```
this.parentNode.style.display="none"
```

To disable the row (`<tr>`-tag).

Otherwise you remove the css again to show them.

The disadvantage with this is, that the reduced result is only shown to the user, but for using the reduced version again on a server site, you need to map the result again to checkboxes or maybe hidden fields and send it again.